# what does No such DSL method 'readCSV' means in a jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I need to read a simple csv file and going through the documentation I found this readCSV method which comes with Jenkins, I have set a sample file named test.csv in the workspace folder and use this simple test pipeline:
'''
pipeline {
agent any

```
stages {
    stage('read csv') {
        steps {
            script{
                def records = readCSV file: 'test.csv'
                println records
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
'''
But I keep getting the `No such DSL method 'readCSV'` error and I am not sure what it means, I have read here in SO that usually means you lack a plugin but this does not seem to be the case

Comment: quite clear - no such method in your jenkins instance. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/ check that you have plugin installed.

Comment: @dagget there is no such readCSV plugin the method comes with Jenkins

Comment: i gave you a link, there is a reference to plugin page: https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps/ just check that you have latest version of this plugin

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the [pipeline-utility-steps plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps) was not installed and I thought it was installed by default, in case anyone else faces the same issue.